# Perl need the right grep operator to match value of variable

Tags: perl, grep

I want to see if I have repeated items in my array, there are over 16.000 so will automate it
There may be other ways but I started with this and, well, would like to finish it unless there is a straightforward command. What I am doing is shifting and pushing from one array into another and this way, check the destination array to see if it is "in array" (like there is such a command in PHP).

So, I got this sub routine and it works with literals, but it doesn't with variables. It is because of the 'eq' or whatever I should need. The 'sourcefile' will contain one or more of the words of the destination array.

```
// Here I just fetch my file


    $listamails = <STDIN>;
    # Remove the newlines filename
    chomp $listamails;
    # open the file, or exit
    unless ( open(MAILS, $listamails) ) {

    print "Cannot open file \"$listamails\"\n\n";
    exit;
    }
    # Read the list of mails from the file, and store it
    # into the array variable @sourcefile
    @sourcefile = <MAILS>;
    # Close the handle - we've read all the data into @sourcefile now.
    close MAILS;


    my @destination = ('hi', 'bye');

    sub in_array
    {
       my ($destination,$search_for) = @_;
       return grep {$search_for eq $_} @$destination;
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <=100; $i ++)

    {
      $elemento = shift @sourcefile;
      if(in_array(\@destination, $elemento))
      {
        print  "it is";
      }
      else
      {
        print "it aint there";
      }
    }
```

Well, if instead of including the $elemento in there I put a 'hi' it does work and also I have printed the value of $elemento which is also 'hi', but when I put the variable, it does not work, and that is because of the 'eq', but I don't know what else to put. If I put == it complains that 'hi' is not a numeric value.

Comment: A couple of side-bugs: `$i < scalar @sourcefile -1` shouldn't have the `-1` at the end, and can in fact become just `$i < @sourcefile` since the scalar context on the right-hand side of `<` will automatically Do What You Mean here.  Also `@sourcefile` is shrinking by 1 each iteration due to the `shift`, so your current `for` loop condition will wind up looking at only half the elements!  Either replace the `shift` with a read of `$sourcefile[$i]` and leave the `for` condition as `$i < @sourcefile`, or change the `for` condition to `@sourcefile > 0` or just `@sourcefile`.

Comment: yes, yes, realized that before that it was actually shrinking at twice the speed because of that, fixed it elsewhere and forgot to copy it here, anyway I can change the for without a problem, but still I have the core issue.. thank you

Comment: If `@sourcefile` contains lines read from a file, the most likely problem is that they will end with a newline (`\n`) character (or possibly a carriage-return, newline sequence (`\r\n`) if you're reading a file that was created in Windows under UNIX.  You can get rid of a trailing `\n` with `chomp`.  To get rid of a trailing `\r`, I use `s/\r\z//;`.

Comment: So you  mean, the grep command is correct? it should work as it is ?

Comment: I suspect there could be spaces or other unseen characters hiding in there.  I would recommend installing a module called Data::Dump, adding `use Data::Dump 'pp';` near the top of your program, and then adding `print pp($elemento);` in your code to rule this out.

Comment: You are not deleting the `\n` characters that you read into `@sourcefile` with `@sourcefile = <MAILS>;`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, when looking for duplicates in a large number of items, it's much faster to use a strategy based on **sorting**.  After sorting the items, all duplicates will be right next to each other, so to tell if something is a duplicate, all you have to do is compare it with the previous one:

```
@sorted = sort @sourcefile;
for (my $i = 1; $i < @sorted; ++$i) {   # Start at 1 because we'll check the previous one
    print "$sorted[$i] is a duplicate!\n" if $sorted[$i] eq $sorted[$i - 1];
}
```

This will print multiple dupe messages if there are multiple dupes, but you can clean it up.

Comment: Well, yes, definitively that should work, I ll give you the useful help. I will keep it in the pocket as a solution. Now I think I have only left the curiosity of knowing whether the 'eq' should work with the variable $elemento. (could remove all lines except the first one so as to eliminate the sure carriage return and new lines.

Comment: This is true in the general case for most programming languages, but hash-based solutions tend to be faster in Perl than sorting-based ones on large data sets because hash operations are O(1), while sorting is (at best) O(log n).

Comment: @Dave: I agree with you *except* for large datasets ;)  Hashes are fast until you run out of memory, at which point they become abysmally slow, while sorting (admittedly external sorting, not Perl's internal `sort()`) can be done fast in external memory.

Comment: Fair point. I was assuming datasets which are large, but not too large to fit into memory. Although I wonder how a tied/DBM hash would stack up against an external sort in that case...  (Not to mention that it's now getting to be large enough that an SQL database might be more appropriate in any case.)

Comment: What you say isn't true. Sorting is not faster, *especially* for large number of items. A linear search assisted with a hash is faster. `say "$_ is a duplicate" for grep ++$seen{$_} >= 2, @sourcefile;` And it's even easy to avoid dupliacte messages (by changing `>=` to `==`).

Comment: @j_random_hacker, hashes can be done in external memory too. Note that doing it using external memory just magnifies the problem of sorting being slower.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm not aware of any efficient external-memory hashing algorithms -- do you have a link?  TTBOMK all hashes are designed so that hashing 2 different keys x and y will produce 2 hash codes h(x) and h(y) so that h(x) - h(y) is large with high probability, which guarantees terrible (approaching disk-seek-per-lookup) performance once the hashtable size >> working memory.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I didn't necessarily mean "hash table" when I said "hash".

Comment: @ikegami: What do you mean then? Is there a faster way of using hash tables for the task at hand or not?

Comment: @ikegami: Please either back up your claims or delete them, thanks.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, That there exists efficient ways of locating a record by key? Funny how databases do it all the time.

Comment: @ikegami: What does locating a record by key have to do with anything?  We want to find whether there are any duplicates (and perhaps what those dupes are).  Do you really think it will be faster to insert all the keys into a B+-tree (typical data structure backing a RDBMS) and then use a self-join query to find the dupes, than to simply use an external sort algorithm like the `sort` included with all *nix systems?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, we're talking about an external associative array. What did you think we're talking about?

Comment: @ikegami: Read the question: "I want to see if I have repeated items in my array".

Comment: @ikegami: Your comment "... we're talking about an external associative array" makes no sense to me. *That's* what I'm comparing my external-sorting approach to -- to using an external associative array in the form of a B+ tree or similar (used by all sane RDBMSes, Berkeley DB etc). The best way to use a B+ tree to find dupes would be have it ordered by the key, add the keys, and then just read them out in sorted order noting dupes as you go. Doing this will be slower than simply doing an external sort, for the same reason that sorting in-memory is faster than building a binary tree in memory.

Answer (score 4):

When you want distinct values think hash.

```
my %seen;
@seen{ @array } = (); 

if (keys %seen == @array) {
    print "\@array has no duplicate values\n";
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify how this works, `if (keys %seen == @array)` tests to see whether the _number or items_ in `%seen` and `@array` are the same. It does not compare the actual items in each list against the other list. In this case, that will work perfectly, but it is not a general-purpose way of determining equality between two lists. (I assume you know this eugene, but it should be noted for the sake of those less familiar with Perl.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want. If your first sentence is the only one that matters ("I want to see if I have repeated items in my array"), then you could use:

```
my %seen;
if (grep ++$seen{$_} >= 2, @array) {
   say "Has duplicates";
}
```

You said you have a large array, so it might be faster to stop as soon as you find a duplicate.

```
my %seen;
for (@array) {
   if (++$seen{$_} == 2) {
      say "Has duplicates";
      last;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [eugene y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274497/18914) said, hashes are definitely the way to go here.  Here's a direct translation of the code you posted to a hash-based method (with a little more Perlishness added along the way):

```
my @destination = ('hi', 'bye');
my %in_array = map { $_ => 1 } @destination;

for my $i (0 .. 100) {
  $elemento = shift @sourcefile;
  if(exists $in_array{$elemento})
  {
    print  "it is";
  }
  else
  {
    print "it aint there";
  }
}
```

Also, if you mean to check all elements of `@sourcefile` (as opposed to testing the first 101 elements) against `@destination`, you should replace the `for` line with

```
while (@sourcefile) {
```

Also also, don't forget to `chomp` any values read from a file!  Lines read from a file have a linebreak at the end of them (the `\r\n` or `\n` mentioned in comments on the initial question), which will cause both `eq` and hash lookups to report that otherwise-matching values are different.  This is, most likely, the reason why your code is failing to work correctly in the first place and changing to use `sort` or hashes won't fix that.  First `chomp` your input to make it work, then use `sort` or hashes to make it efficient.